# deploy my REST Api service project to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We are having a application developed in MVC 4.

Here are our scenarios:

1) we are following plugin architecture, so we are having other projects which can plugin into the main web application.Right now we are using installshield to deploy our dlls from other projects into the main web application.
How can we do when publishing the main web application as Azure App service.
Is there any feature in Azure so that we can remove the install Sheild and use some properties in Azure to move the dlls from other projects to the main web application folder.

2)We have logging feature enabled so the logs are maintained in local File store under AppData folder and upload the same log file to Db and delete the local log file? How can we achieve the same if moved to Azure App service?

3)Our MVC application calls the another Service application using rest Api calls.Currently we are mentioning the service details in config file under MVC application.
if we are moving to Azure how about the configuration properties mentioned in my MVC Application to call the Service project.

To start with, *I  would like to deploy my REST Api service project to Azure.My project is a class library and please help how can move my service project to Azure App service and get the server name*.

Comment: I don't quite understand the challenge here. You are not migrating your app from MVC4 to Azure. thats like saying, you are migrating from watching a movie at home to driving a car. I think you are trying to ask 'Migrating the MVC app running on a local web server to a Azure App (website) service. could you clarify this?

Comment: I am trying to understand how my application behaves if deployed to azure and problems occur in case of point 2 and point 3.

Comment: well, why did you not say that? The title is hopelessly misleading. In that case, you should deploy it first (obvious thing to do) and then let us know the issues you ran into. We can help you if you run into issues but not before it happens.

Comment: OK. First I would like to deploy my REST Api service project to Azure.My project is a class library and please help how can move my service project to Azure App service and get the server name.

Comment: alright, I have edited your question to update your requirement. Once the edit gets approved, you will starting seeing relevant answers below.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Plugin Architecture

We had a similar requirement but we were not using InstallShield for copying plugin DLLs to our web app, instead what we did was created the following folder structure:

- -- MVC Application
- ---- bin
- ---- App_Plugins
- ------- Plugin1
- ------------ Release DLLs
- ------- Plugin2
- ------------ Release DLLs
- -- Plugins (actual source code)
- ---- Plugin1
- ---- Plugin2

and set the output directory of our Plugin 1 and Plugin 2 to point to the ..\App_Plugins\Plugin1\

and we simply published this app directly to Azure Website and that worked like a charm.

Then we found out about CI/CD process on VSTS and that changed everything, it gave us a more elegant way of managing all of this. Can provide more details if you need that.

> 2 Logging Feature

If all your logging code & logic for moving all this to DB is within the application, then you should not have to worry about anything and it should work without any challenges as long as you setup your DB connections correctly.

> 3 REST API settings in config file

The web.config file of your MVC application is published along with the rest of your application. so, as long as your settings are mentioned in the web.config and they work locally, it should all work fine in Azure as well.

Comment: 2)The code for logging is available in another service project( VS solution) which will store in Db.The service is like a scheduler which will upload logs at regular intervals.Please let me know if this will supported in azure.

Comment: 3)Currently we are deploying our service application which is following(Plugin architecture) initially and mentioning the server name and port number in Web application config file. While deploying in Azure can we get server name and port to mention in config file of Web application.Or the server name and port number will dynamically change

Comment: 2) create a webjob or use a Azure function to do that. 
3) In azure you will need to use FQDN and wont have server name / port provided as such unless you are using a VM to host your service application. when you move any application to azure web app, it automatically generates a FQDN http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net which can be customised to have a custom domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

Start here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

Ensure you already have a Azure account, and of course visual studio has the Azure SDK installed (it may be required).